# Why is this sorting function returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, function, sorting, undefined

The result that's logged to the console (*answer*) is the correct one, but it's coming out of the function as undefined. What is going on?

```
let sorted = [];

function reset(){
    sorted = [];
}

function sort(list) {
    let least = list[0];
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        if (list[i] < least ){
            least = list[i];
        }
    }
    sorted.push(least);
    list.splice(list.indexOf(least),1);
    if (list[0] !== undefined){
        sort(list)
    }
    else {
        let answer = sorted;
        reset();
        console.log(answer);
        return answer;
    }
}
let sampleArray = [3,2,1];
sort(sampleArray);
```

Comment: In your `if` branch you have no `return`, which means you get the default return value (`undefined`).

Answer (score 1):

In the `if` branch you correctly call `sort` recursively, but just ignore the returned value instead of returning it. Just return it and you should be fine:

```
if (list[0] !== undefined) {
    return sort(list); // Here
}
else {
    // Rest of your code...
```

Answer (score 0):

[@Mureinik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49882308/1541563) is correct about the problem. However, more to the point, if you want to make a sorted copy of the array in increasing order, you can easily do so using [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```js
let sampleArray = [3, 1, 2];
// sorted array
let sortedArray = sampleArray.slice().sort((a, b) => a - b);

console.log(sortedArray);
// original array preserved
console.log(sampleArray);
```

(I'm getting a 500 error so [here's an alternative demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7a0v26kr/) for now)